# Keep audio play while refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I know we can use AJAX to change page area so the page is not closed (then audio will not stop), but what if I pressed the refresh button? I have Googled a lot but didn't find a solution.

This is possible, because `Jamendo` has implemented this feature (Even in the refreshing process, the music continues playing).

Comment: What is Jamendo? It sounds like this question is a plant or plug, promoting him or it, or he's actually done this, in which case it sounds like what he's done is a hack, along the lines of hiding a second window (not recommended). You said it's possible, please give more information on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prevent the refresh of the page using the `F5` button using Javascript.

```
if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault();
```

[update]
The above works great but regarding the browser refresh button and `CTRL + R` I've just confirmed the following will force a pop-up to the user to confirm they want to leave.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {return false;}
```

Why not just use AJAX?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes I have used AJAX when navigating pages, but client asked me to keep the player running even refreshing the page..